# Mounting ftp directory to docker container

Tags: docker

I was wondering if it is possible to mount a directory from ftp server to my docker container? So whenever someone sends files to the server the files will also be in my container.

Comment: Why dont you use volumes wich are more practical than mounts

Answer (score 0):

You can mount or add volumes only locally on machine where docker hosts.

If your FTP and docker on the same machine you can create docker volume and after that set up your FTP and use docker volume location for it.

The second way described here [docker FTP container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37955086/2211265)